# makemigrations doesn't add any column, except id column

Tags: python, migrate, makemigrations

After creating `app1` and adding it in `INSTALLED_APPS`, I wrote my model in **models.py** including a table with two columns, `cod` & `name`, then typed in Terminal:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app1
```

and

```
python migrate
```

It worked, but the only thing created is a table with a column named `id`, without my columns (`cod` & `name`)

and when I change my model, for example add new field or change `max_length` or etc it answered:

```
No change detected in app app1
```

my database is postgresql, localhost

**models.py:**

```py
    from django.db import models


    class BookList(models.Model):
        Cod: models.SmallIntegerField()
        Name: models.CharField(max_length=20)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.Name
```

Comment: Use the equal sign instead of Colon. I guess it might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i got it, should use `=` instead of `:` in definition of columns in model
thank myself